# How to take a generator of a polynomial ring in Sage? and specify an arbitrary ring polynomial?

Tags: sage

I'm wondering how I can introduce arbitrary variables in a polynomial ring i.e:

R.<x1,...,xn> = PolynomialRing(k)

where k is a finite field given.

And I also want to take the specific elements [x1,...,xn] of the ring, do you have some idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't introduce an arbitrary number of variables (that is, indexed by an unspecified `n`). You can do this, though:

```
sage: R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'x', 10)
sage: R
Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9 over Rational Field
sage: R.inject_variables()
Defining x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9
```

At this point you can use `x3` or any of the others.

You can also do:

```
sage: R.<x> = InfinitePolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: R
Infinite polynomial ring in x over Rational Field
sage: x[0]
x_0
sage: x[135]
x_135
sage: 3*x[1]^2 * x[232]
3*x_232*x_1^2
```

Comment: Is possible specify var('x'+str(i)) like a element of a previously fixed polynomial field?

Comment: `var(...)` produces a symbolic variable: not the same as an element of a polynomial ring. `R.gen(3)` will produce the third generator, so you could do `x3 = R.gen(3)`.

Comment: You can also do `R('x' + str(i))` for suitable values of `i`.